# Diagram to show differences in distributions of sample scores

Tags: distributions, data-visualization

What diagram could I use to illustrate differences in distribution of sample scores? That is, how can I show whether they are from the same population or different populations?

Comment: I mean to show whether they are from the same population or different populations...

Comment: You can't show things "are from the same population". It's not logically possible without enumerating the entire population and showing they're both subsets of it.. You can sometimes show that they're not, or rather that they're so unalike for them to be from the same population would imply a bizarre happenstance, but if two samples happen to be very similar it carries no counter-implication of having the same distribution.

Comment: What are these sample scores of, how are they calculated? Are they categorical, notionally continuous, discrete? Are the scores paired or dependent in any way (e.g. measured on the same individuals?) What sort of sample sizes might you have? tens? thousands? millions?